# best practice for adding object to arrays

Tags: javascript

```
    this.state = {
    post: {
        question: '',
        img: '',
        postId: '',
        userId: ''
      },
    feed: [],
  }
```

What is the best practice for adding an object to an array.

Comment: First: does `post` have to be an array? Second: If there are multiple items in the `post` array, how do you decide which one to change the `question` value for?

Comment: each post has an Id

Comment: There seems to be a few fishy things here. If `post` is an array of posts call it `posts`, otherwise no need to put it in an array. Secondly, the fact that you are using `setState` informs me that this state is internal to the component, and updating here is not making any kind of HTTP request. If that is the case, you should probably have another component here called `Post` that handles the state of a single post rather than trying to update an in-component state array.

Comment: but if you want to do it this way, you will need to pass a `postId` (or even an index) into `handleChange` to inform the callback which post in the array should be updated.

Comment: Can't you simply do `arrayName.push(object);`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need some corrections with `state`:

```
this.state = {
  posts: [],
  feeds: [],
}
```

In a future *Posts* will be an `Array of Objects` for example:

```
this.state = {
  posts: [
   { postid: 1, question: "question" },
   { postid: 2, question: "question" }
  ]
}
```

Use `this.setState` to add a new post to posts, also keep in mind the `state` is **immutable**:

```
const newpost = { id: 1, question: "question" };
this.setState({
  posts: this.state.posts.concat(newpost)
  // or with rest operator posts: [...this.state.posts, newpost]
})
```

More about `state` [React State](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate)

An example **JSFiddle**

```js
class Example extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      posts: [],
      feed: [],
    }
  }

  getName = () => {
    const names = ['One', 'Two', 'Three', 'Four', 'Five', 'Six']
    const random = Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length);
    return names[random]
  };
  
  getId = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * (9999-1)) + 1;
  
  makePost = () => ({ id: this.getId(), name: this.getName() });
  
  createPost = () => {
    this.setState({
      // Rest operators ensure a new object with merged properties and values.
      // Requires the "transform-object-rest-spread" Babel plugin
      posts: [...this.state.posts, this.makePost()]
      // Or like this: this.state.posts.concat(this.makePost())
    })
  };
  
  render() {
    
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={this.createPost}>Create Post</button>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify(this.state, null, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Example />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```